# Silk-screened 'buttons' on a touch-tone phone?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I've been taking apart a recent, standard touch tone phone with the aim for automated dialing via a separate MCU with transistors activating the contacts (Smirk. An assistive technologies project designed for my grandmother, not 'robo-calling').

Removing the solder mask it is quite clear how to accomplish this in this case--

However, I had another question: Namely, does anyone know what process/method is being used here to trigger the switches ?

Rather than any physical device, the button contacts seem to be overlaid on the board themselves with a type of 'black substrate'. No visible connections are already apparent between the buttons.

At first I thought perhaps captive touch, but then they are activated by basically a rubber pad on the matching side, plus a plastic 'number button' on top.

My second thought here was that somehow the button press might be creating 'arcing'-- but could the voltage really be so high in this case?

I wondered if anyone had any thoughts as to what is going on, or what process is being used?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not any sort of touch technology. These are old fashioned [silicon rubber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_rubber_keypad) buttons. The pads on the PCB are carbon coated to prevent oxidation of a tinned finish. Immersion gold and silver can also be used. The black pads on the buttons are conductive (put a DMM across them, you'll measure a low resistance), and physically pushed down to contact the PCB pads. It functions like any normal normally open push button. No magic here.

Comment: Dear Matt, thanks for the quick response. You are correct, in this case I am averaging around ~70/80 ohms. At first they just appeared like standard rubber to me-- So based on the Wiki article, are these black pads 'doped' in some way? Or I am not quite sure what they mean by a 'pill' in the button ? A solid contact which is able to conduct through the material, or particles spread small and even through out? Thanks again. Happy Easter.

Comment: @AnthonyBalducci I don't use this style of button often, but apparaent pill is the industry name for the button pad. It's a passive device, no doping. They can adjust the resistance of the pill material per application requirements. The material itself is not far removed from pencil lead.